# Jquery animation on scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and if I use it the scroll efect is not working, but if I change the duration from 500 to 50 everything is ok.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    $( window ).scroll( scrollWindow );
});
function scrollWindow(){
    var newScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    var height = $( window ).height();
    if( currentScrollTop > newScrollTop ){
        var newPosition = currentScrollTop - height;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
        });
    }
    else if( currentScrollTop < newScrollTop ){
        var newPosition = currentScrollTop + height;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
        });
    }
}
```

I have fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/whwkv47q/4/)

Comment: *You may want to take a look at [this](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-scroll-animations-with-fullpagejs-and-animatecss--cms-25235) article.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here:

**1.** You never update `currentScrollTop`.

**2.** You need to restrict the scroll event from being re-triggered while the page is already scrolling. You can remove the event while the animation is happening by using `.off` (i've modified your event handler to use `.on` instead of `.scroll` for this purpose), and then rebind it when the animation completes.

---

**Solution:** [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/whwkv47q/10/) (I've added an adjustable input for testing, so you can change scroll speed.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    $( window ).on("scroll", scrollWindow );
});

function scrollWindow(){

    var newScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    var height = $( window ).height();
    console.log(newScrollTop);
    if( currentScrollTop > newScrollTop ){
        var newPosition = currentScrollTop - height;

        //Remove our scroll event during animation
        $(window).off();

        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();

             //Rebind event after animation complete
            $( window ).on("scroll", scrollWindow );

        });
    }
    else if( currentScrollTop < newScrollTop ){

        //Remove our scroll event during animation
        $(window).off();

        var newPosition = currentScrollTop + height;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500, function(){
            currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();

            //Rebind event after animation complete
            $( window ).on("scroll", scrollWindow );

        });
    }

    //Update scrollTop
    currentScrollTop = newScrollTop();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wait for a while on the fiddle, you can see the scrolling effect working. Actually when the duration parameter of your animate function is 500 it is relatively slower than when it is at 50. So as you move towards higher values, you are slowing down the scroll speed. You can see this doc for reference. Also you can use strings like 'slow' and 'fast' instead of 500 or 50 for your animation duration.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#duration

Or you can use a timeout. Try this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
var timeout;
$(window).scroll(function() {
clearTimeout(timeout);  
timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    var newScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
var height = $( window ).height();
if( currentScrollTop > newScrollTop ){
    var newPosition = currentScrollTop - height;
    $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500,
function(){
        currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    });
}
else if( currentScrollTop < newScrollTop ){
    var newPosition = currentScrollTop + height;
    $( "html, body" ).animate({ scrollTop: newPosition }, 500,function(){
        currentScrollTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
    });
}

}, 50);});});
```

Comment: That's way more than *500 milliseconds* after a scroll @Ankur; you can't say **the scrolling effect working**. No way!

Comment: Only first scroll is working fine when it is set to 500... I want slower scroll effect which is working on every scroll. Any advice?

Comment: Actually your handler scrollWindow is called more than once for a scroll, hence the reason 500 milliseconds is too long for that. You can use alert to see the number of time it gets called. It gets called twice precisely. I ve edited my answer , you can use this script, it works fine.

Comment: "So your code is waiting for 500 milliseconds before it scrolls down and again it waits for another 500 milliseconds." This is incorrect. `500` refers to the time the scroll animation takes to complete, not the "wait duration".

Comment: @Santi yes sorry for that. i deleted that line. Poor choice of words :p